# Do not change tab title

Tags: ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

When I change controller's `self.title`, tab title also changes to that string.

Is it any workaround to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `UITabBarController`:

> If you do not provide a custom tab bar item for your view controller,
>   the view controller creates a default item containing no image and the
>   text from the view controller’s title property.

So you can either instantiate your own `UITabBarItem` and assign it to the view controller’s `tabBarItem` property.

Or simply just add a new property to your `UIViewController` that can store the string:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myTitle;
```

And then use that property instead:
    `self.myTitle = @"Your title here";`

Comment: I didn't understand about property, that can store string? Can you please clarify?

Comment: OK, now I see... But I want to modify title a few times, so property isn't really a good solution

Comment: A property is just an automatic way to generate (synthesize) getters and setters for an instance variable. You can modify the property as much as you like.